# Why does the C# compiler allow a cast to be performed with Linq but not with parentheses?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, casting

I have a generic class `NamedValue<TValue>`:

```
public class NamedValue<TValue>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have a second generic class, `NamedValueSource<TValue>` that contains a `List<NamedValue<TValue>>`:

```
public class NamedValueSource<TValue>
{
    public List<NamedValue<TValue>> NamedValues { get; set; }

    public NamedValueSource()
    {
        NamedValues = GetNamedValues().Cast<NamedValue<TValue>>().ToList();
    }

    private IEnumerable<NamedValue<bool>> GetNamedValues()
    {
        var yesNamedValue = new NamedValue<bool> { Name = "Yes", Value = true };
        var noNamedValue = new NamedValue<bool> { Name = "Yes", Value = false };
        yield return yesNamedValue;
        yield return noNamedValue;
    }
}
```

The following test code works perfectly (the assertion passes):

```
public class Tester
{
    public Tester()
    {
        var source = new NamedValueSource<bool>();
        Debug.Assert(source.NamedValues[0].Name == "Yes");
    }
}
```

Now, here's the interesting part. If I attempt to perform the cast within `GetNamedValues()`, the code won't compile:

```
public class NamedValueSourceFail<TValue>
{
    public List<NamedValue<TValue>> NamedValues { get; set; }

    public NamedValueSourceFail()
    {
        NamedValues = GetNamedValues().ToList();
    }

    private IEnumerable<NamedValue<TValue>> GetNamedValues()
    {
        var yesNamedValue = new NamedValue<bool> { Name = "Yes", Value = true };
        var noNamedValue = new NamedValue<bool> { Name = "Yes", Value = false };
        yield return (NamedValue<TValue>)yesNamedValue; // ERROR: cannot convert type
        yield return (NamedValue<TValue>)noNamedValue; // ERROR: cannot convert type
    }
}
```

Why does `NamedValueSource<TValue>` compile while `NamedValueSourceFail<TValue>` errors out? Specifically, why am I able to perform the cast using Linq but not with good ol' parantheses?

**Edit**

In case it's not entirely clear from the comment thread of the accepted answer, I simply needed to convert to `object` first, then I would be allowed to cast to `NamedValue<TValue>`. This is probably how the Linq `Cast` method works behind the scenes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your second example, you're trying to convert `NamedValue<bool>` to `NamedValue<TValue>` -- this won't work, because the conversion has to be valid for any type argument.  You can't convert `NamedValue<bool>` to `NamedValue<int>` or `NamedValue<string>` or `NamedValue<AnythingElseOtherThanBool>`.

One solution is to make `NamedValueSource<TValue>` abstract, as well as its `GetNamedValues()` method, and then create a class `BooleanNamedValueSource : NamedValueSource<bool>` class to use in your test.

In the linq case, the cast is not being done by the compiler; the cast occurs in a method that has already been compiled.  All the compiler knows is that it is calling a method that takes `IEnumerable<bool>` and returns `IEnumerable<TValue>`.  The specifics of that conversion are entirely invisible to the compiler.

Comment: I get why it won't work for the second example...what I don't get is why it *does* work for the first example.

Comment: You said that the compiler works for the first example, does it actually work at runtime though?  According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx it will be a deferred execution meaning that the cast won't be evaluated until runtime, and if it is invalid then an exeception will be thrown.

Comment: Because in the first example, the return type of the method is `IEnumerable<NamedValue<bool>>`.  This means, among other things, that if you made a `NamedValueSource<string>` instance with that implementation, its `GetNamedValues` method would return a sequence of `NamedValue<bool>` -- not what you want, of course, but it should help explain why the method compiles and runs.

Comment: @scwagner yes, it should work, because the method's return type is `IEnumerable<NamedValue<bool>>`, so of course you can `yield return` the objects.  The problem is that this means that *all `NamedValueSource<TValue>` return sequences of `NamedValue<bool>`,* which is no doubt an incorrect implementation.

Comment: @phoog, But why should it matter whether I cast before or after I receive the result? Look at the `Cast` Linq expression in the first example. It's the same exact cast I'm not allowed to do in the second example.

Comment: The test code provided works because `var source = new NamedValueSource<bool>()` ends up making `TValue` be `bool` which is of course cast compatible with itself.  If you switch the type of `source` to be `NamedValueSource<string>`, does it still execute just fine is what I'm asking.

Comment: @DanM the Cast linq expression will fail at run time if you instantiate the class with any type argument other than `bool`.  The linq `Cast` method does a run-time type check but the second example won't get past the compiler.  You can force it past the compiler by inserting a cast to object: `yield return (NamedValue<TValue>)(object)yesNamedValue;`

Comment: @scwagner ah, yes, I misunderstood your question.  Of course it will fail at run time for any type argument other than `bool`.

Comment: @scwagner, the answer is of course, no, it doesn't work (I get an "unable to cast" error). What I'm trying to get at here is why Linq is actually behaving "dynamically" here? The compiler knows at compile time that `TValue` might not be a bool or convertible to bool, yet it allows it to compile for one way or coding but not another.

Comment: @DanM in the Linq case, the compiler is not doing any analysis about the cast; the cast is being done in a method that has already been compiled.  I added a bit to the answer.

Comment: Ok, @DanM, then that should answer your question.  The compiler knows that the cast doesn't work, and throws an error.  When you switch to LINQ, then the compiler says "I don't know, this might work, you'll find out at runtime" and that's when it fails instead.

Comment: @scwagner, so Linq is a actually enabling dynamic behavior that is not available with "regular C#" acting on a single object?

Comment: @DanM not at all.  As I pointed out, you can get that behavior by casting first to object, which tells the compiler "I know better than you that this conversion should work, or might work, and I want you to defer the type check to the runtime".  That's the same sort of cast that you get in the generic `Cast` method.

Comment: It's not enabling anything, the cast still fails for anything where `TValue` is not directly cast-able from `bool`.  It just switches the cast attempt from compile-time to run-time.  It doesn't magically make it legal for it to happen regardless of the type of `TValue`.  The reason the compiler rejects the hard-coded cast to `TValue` is because it knows that it can't legally do that for all possible values of `TValue`.  I don't think I can explain the distinction any more clearly, sorry.

Comment: @phoog, Sorry, I missed that in the stream of comments. I feel better now :)

Comment: @scwagner, See phoog's most recent comment. Basically, you can defer any cast to runtime by first casting to object then casting to whatever type you want. I just didn't realize Linq was doing that behind the scenes.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE**: This question was [the subject of my blog on July 10th 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/07/10/when-is-a-cast-not-a-cast.aspx); thanks for the great question!

---

Let's greatly simplify your complicated program.

```
public static class X
{
    public static V Cast<V>(object o) { return (V)o; }
}

class C<T> {}
class D<U>
{
    public C<U> value;
    public D()
    {
        this.value = X.Cast<C<U>>(new C<bool>());
    }
}
```

Now your second version, simplified:

```
class C<T> {}
class D<U>
{
    public C<U> value;
    public D()
    {
        this.value = (C<U>)(new C<bool>());
    }
}
```

OK, so now let's ask some questions.

> Why does the second program fail at compile time?

Because there is no conversion from `C<bool>` to `C<U>` for arbitrary `U`. The compiler knows that the *only* way this could *possibly* succeed is is `U` is *always* bool, and therefore this program is almost certainly wrong! The compiler assumes that `U` is going to be something other than bool some of the time.

> Why then does the first program succeed at compile time?

The compiler has no idea that a method named "X.Cast" should be treated like a cast operator for the purposes of error detection! As far as the compiler is concerned, the `Cast` method is a method that takes an object in and returns a `V` for whatever type parameter is provided for `V`. When compiling the body of the ctor of D, the compiler has no idea whatsoever that some method, which probably isn't even in this program to begin with, is going to try to do a cast that is going to fail unless `U` happens to be bool.

The compiler simply has no basis upon which to treat the first version as an error, even though it most certainly is a deeply wrong program.  You'll have to wait until runtime to find out that your program is wrong.

Now let's make a *third* version of your program:

```
class C<T> {}
class D<U>
{
    public C<U> value;
    public D()
    {
        this.value = (C<U>)(object)(new C<bool>());
    }
}
```

This succeeds at compile time, so let's ask:

> Why does this succeed at compile time?

For the exact same reason that the first one succeeds at compile time. When you inserted the cast you effectively said that you wanted the newly constructed `C<bool>` to be treated as an object, and so for the rest of the analysis of this expression, that expression is considered to be of type object, and not the more specific type `C<bool>`.

> So then why is it legal to cast object to `C<U>` in this case? Or for that matter, to `V` in the first case?

It is legal to cast object to `V` because `V` could be the type of the object, a base type of the object or an interface implemented by the object, so the compiler allows the conversion because it figures there are a lot of ways it could possibly succeed.

Basically, it is legal to cast `object` to *anything that you could convert to `object`*. You cannot cast `object` to a pointer type, for instance, because no pointer type can be cast to `object`. But everything else is fair game.

By making the cast to `object` first, you are *removing information* from the purview of the compiler; you are saying "ignore the fact that you know this is always `C<bool>` for the purposes of error detection.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. The key nugget of info I wasn't getting is that if you first cast an instance of a specific type to an `object` (boxing), you are then free to cast it to anything. This will defer the validation check to runtime.

Comment: @DanM correct, except that casting to object is not boxing unless the thing you're casting is a struct/value type.  Boxing does not apply to classes/reference types.

Comment: Well we have to upvote him yet again:) - I knew all this but you always here something new on how things work (I was always treating this as 'closed' vs 'open' generic types and it's logical it cannot work - but I haven't been thinking like a 'compiler')

Comment: @phoog, An interesting wrinkle in all this: Let's say you have a double myDouble set to 1.0. Now you want to cast it to a TNumber (TNumber happens to be an int, but this isn't known until runtime). Using `var myValue = (TNumber)(object)myDouble` will fail. This surprised me a bit because `int myInt = (int)myDouble` would have succeeded. So basically, if you know TNumber is some kind of number, there seems to be no easy way out of this besides checking if typeof(TValue) is an int, then doing `(TValue)(object)Convert.ToInt32(myDouble)`.

Comment: @DanM: You are correct. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx for some thoughts on why that is. Basically, the reason is: what code would we generate? We'd have to generate a call to `Convert.ToInt32` for you, which might surprise people because that code is quite slow. If that's what you want to happen, then you can write that call yourself and make it clear in the code instead of hiding it in the codegen.

Comment: Eric, interesting. I hadn't thought of using `dynamic` instead of `object`. Probably not worth it for my current situation, but I'll remember it's an option next time I face a similar situation.

Comment: @DanM you have in fact discovered that the technique of casting through `object` (or another common base type) applies *only* to reference types.  It fails not only with numbers but with all value types.  I was not thinking of that during the discussion in the comments to my answer.